# matlab cell insertion problem

Tags: matlab, image-processing, compiler-errors, cell

I am trying to convert a coloured image to grayscale, resize it and put it into a cell. I wrote the following code for that. But I am getting an error. What am I doing wrong?
code:

```
x=imread(strcat('E:\Documents and Settings\brahadeesh\Desktop\will\101_ObjectCategories\airplanes\',files_a(i).name));
x=imresize(x,[32 32]);
x=rgb2gray(x);
a(i-3)=x;
```

error:

```
??? Conversion to cell from uint8 is not possible.
Error in ==> *** at 16
a(i-3)=x;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `a` has been initialized as a cell array, you have to use curly braces to [index and replace the *content* of a cell](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-98.html#br04bw6-108):

```
a{i-3} = x;
```